# Reading .csv file from Multipart Content - not read as FileData

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am building a WebAPI call which takes an uploaded .csv file, reads that file, and then takes action based on the contents. At least, that's what it should do.

I'm working with code found in the [ASP.NET documentation](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) and in many other places, all of which indicate that my file contents should be read into `provider.FileData`. However, they are being read into `provider.FormData` as if they were more generic form elements. It exists there as one long string, with inconsistent separators and no key/value pairs to work with. I've been poring over SO questions but haven't found anything that helps.

How can I either get the file to read into FileData, or parse the contents from FormData?

In Controller:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ImportPersons()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        if (!provider.FileData.Any()) //evaluated as true
            throw new InvalidOperationException("File does not contain any data.");

        var personsToImport = new List<Persons>();
        foreach (var record in provider.FileData)
        {
           //handle file contents
           //code omitted
        }
```

In View (simplified):

I guessed that the program might be seeing my file as a simple form input based on where it ended up, but changing this to include just a single file upload input didn't affect the issue.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Persons", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<fieldset>
    <div >
        <input type="text" disabled/>
        <span>
            <input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload" accept=".csv" required />
            Browse...
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-submit">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Persons")">Cancel</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Import File"/>
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```